# Muestre el nombre del personal que esta asignado a la penúltima maquinaria con costo mas bajo

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Así va quedando:

```
select top 1 nombres, apellidopat  from personal
where nombres in (select top 2 *
                from personal inner join Asignacion
                on personal.cod_personal= Asignacion.cod_personal
                inner join maquinaria
                on Asignacion.cod_maq = maquinaria.cod_maq
                order by costo_referencial, nombres asc)
order by nombres desc
```

Comment: Buenas. Por favor indica también el modelo de tu BBDD. Para tener una base y que la gente que te pueda ayudar tenga más info

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta?